# javascript auto-incrementing id number

Tags: javascript, auto-increment

I want to create Round ID system that increase the last stored number in json file by one only if some command is ran. Does anyone know how to do it ? Cant find the solution...

```
function roundID(){
   for (var i = 0; i < client.roundID.length; i++) {
     client.roundID[i];
     console.log('there are' + i);
   }
   client.roundID [lastRoundID.toString()] = {
     roundid: '1',
     player: message.author.tag
   }
   fs.writeFile ('roundID.json', JSON.stringify(client.roundID, null, 4), err => {
     if (err) throw err;
   })
 }
```

database:(i want to get the total count of firsts arguments in the database

```
{
"1": {
    "roundid": "1",
    "player": "name"
},
"2": {
    "roundid": "1",
    "player": "name"
}
```

}

Comment: read file, add 1, write file? - there's no "auto-increment" except what you write

Comment: thats why do i ask, i cant find the way how to do it

Comment: you read the file, parse the data, add one to whatever it is you want to add one to, then stringify the object and write back to the file

Comment: main solution i think could be that we use for loop, where we check how many ids are in, and then we increment the number by one, but dont know how to do the for loop

Comment: for example in the json file i have this

Comment: {
    "1": {
        "roundid": "1",
        "player": "name"
    },
    "2": {
        "roundid": "1",
        "player": "name"
    }
}

Comment: loop? see, you haven't shown nearly enough in your question to even require a loop - you should put such useful examples **in the question** not in a comment

Comment: but i dont know how to get the total number by checking the first thing in each registration

Comment: i have added it

Comment: @RobertKráčalík What do you want to do? Please explain what you want to achieve in more detail and clearer words.

Comment: i want to create function that checks how many stored ids are in database (lets call this total number), then create another with id in database, that has id = total number + 1. @LaurentDhont

Comment: @RobertKráčalík Ahn, okay. Just put your players in an array and the next id will be the length of that array.